# How do I separate EJBs from being packaged with my web apps in Netbeans 7?

Tags: web-applications, netbeans, ejb, java-ee-6, netbeans-7

I have 2 different Netbeans projects: an enterprise application holding 2 EJBs and a web application which uses these EJBs.  When I deploy, I deploy them each separately (one as an EAR and the other as a WAR).

We just upgraded our development/production environments from Netbeans 6.8, Glassfish 2.1, Java EE 5 to Netbeans 7, Glassfish 3, Java EE 6.  Now, when I deploy the WAR, the EJBs are automatically deployed with it.  This is undesirable behavior.

Does anyone know how to set it up so that the EJBs are not automatically deployed?  One thought is to simply package the remote interfaces with the WAR...but I'm not sure how to do that within Netbeans.

We're using ant with Netbeans to package our components.  It uses a combination of xml files and properties files, I believe.

Comment: How do you package your components?  Maven?  Ant?  Something build into NetBeans?

Comment: @MarkRobinson Added answer to the original question!

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to move the remote interfaces from the EJB project to a separate EJB interface project.  Then, the EJB project and client projects both included the EJB interface project.